# How to change the shape and add text on navigation dots in fullpage js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

Is it possible to change the shape and the behaviour of navigation dots in fullpage js? like I want to achieve this kind of design, [Click to view this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nOJy.png)

Comment: What did you try? Where is the relevant code?

Comment: You can find similar effects [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/#navigation)